# PHP + vk API: ошибка "extended is accepted only from version 5.0"

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь получить комментарии к записи на стене через API Вконтакте.

Код на php:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getComments');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['count'=>'100', 'post_id'=>$postid, 'version'=>'5.59', 'owner_id'=>"-$ownerid", 'need_likes'=>1, 'sort'=>'asc', 'extended'=>1]);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $out;
}
```

Почему-то отображает ошибку, якобы я использую старую версию API:

> {"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters
>   specified was missing or invalid: extended is accepted only from
>   version
>   5.0","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.getComments"},{"key":"count","value":"100"},{"key":"post_id","value":"48820"},{"key":"version","value":"5.59"},{"key":"owner_id","value":"-112461268"},{"key":"need_likes","value":"1"},{"key":"sort","value":"asc"},{"key":"extended","value":"1"}]}}

Пробовал также передавать значение 'version'=>'5.0', но также вылазит ошибка.

Как быть?

Comment: добавлю, что без 'extended'=>1 все проходит нормально. Но мне нужны расширенные данные также

Comment: скорее всего надо передавать не `'version'=>'5.59'`, а `'v'=>'5.59'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде же, судя по [документации](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests), надо не `version`, а просто `v`.